# Manipulating a MySQL database via MS Access over an SSH connection (PuTTY)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, putty

I use PuTTY to access a remote MySQL database via 'ssh' and then use `mysql` through PuTTY.

Is there any way I could open the same in Microsoft Access database manager and append data to the MySQL table(s) remotely?

I have an Excel file and I want to insert its contents to the MySQL db and it would be very tiresome through putty command line.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the MySQL ODBC driver on your PC: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
Then you can link your MySQL tables to your Access database and use them directly.

Comment: +1 I just confirmed that this approach actually does actually work via [port forwarding in SSH](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding) ("Tunneling") in PuTTY 0.63.

Comment: my que. is i wanna access my db on msacess what i have been accessing on putty. @GordThompson and like i am a newbie so i dunno how.

Answer (score 0):

In linux server access db in local m/c to set tunnel address for putty .